# Property 'follows' not found in Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

the error that appears to me "ErrorException
Trying to get property 'follows' of non-object (View: F:\laragon\www\tweety\resources\views_friends-list.blade.php)"

i'm using Laravel V.6

i'm trying to get a class that gets followers list from User.php but it cant be read by the blade template

the blade file contain the following code

```html
<h3 class="font-bold text-xl mb-4">Following</h3>

<ul>
    @foreach(auth()->user()->follows as $user)
    <li class="mb-4">
        <div>
                <a class="flex items-center text-sm" href="{{route('profile',$tweet->$user)}}">
                <img
                    src="{{$user->avatar}}"
                    alt=""
                    class="rounded-full mr-2"
                >
                    {{$user->name}}

                </a>
           </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

and the function at user.php is

```html
 public function follows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follows', 'user_id', 'following_user_id');
}
```

Comment: the error says you havent set the property follows. Where is your follows() method in user.php?

Comment: *`ErrorException Trying to get property 'follows' of non-object`* it probably try to get `follows` from `null` are you certain you're authenticated ?

Comment: sorry i mentioned a wrong method i have mentioned the right method that i calls it

Comment: no im not authenticated

Comment: then `Auth::user()` would return `null`, since that is for returning the authenticated user

Answer (score 0):

i found it works when i removed the $tweet from the template and it works like that

thanks a lot appreciate your help guys